# How do I run a single Java file having main() in Eclipse, without creating an entire Java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, build, ide

Here's what I've got:

1. I have a `TestFile.java` with the same class name.
2. This class has a valid `main()` method.
3. The file is easily run via terminal using javac and then java, gives intended output.

However, when I drag and drop(or open) the file into Eclipse and try to `Run As`, I don't get `Run As Java Application` or anything that can run that single/independent(of any project) Java file/class.

When I try to just `Run`, I get a pop-up saying "`Run As Ant Build`. Now, I never setup ant build.

All I want is to run just one this Java file and see the output/error in `Console` that is visible just below the editor in perspective.

I didn't and don't intend to write/setup a full fledged Java project with package name and all, in which case `Run as Java Application` simply comes. I just want to run one independent Java class/file in Eclipse with a `main()` method in it.

I am on Mac. If there's any other app/IDE which does that for Java and/or other languages then I think that will be very useful.

**Update**: I created a Java project in Eclipse and a `test.java` inside that and I keep changing/editing/adding in the same file whenever I need to write a quick code and run it. No way to really drag-drop-run in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in Eclipse. You may want to try a simpler tool for that. Perhaps something like SublimeText.

Comment: @AMAR If you want to use `Run as Java Application` you should use Netbean. With Eclipse, you can choose `Run as` and then `Run configuration` and then mount to main method of your class.

Comment: I have a test project in Eclipse for that in which I simply copy the java files... Just keep that project in your workspace and put in whatever you want

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Isn't SublimeText just a text editor? How can I compile and run my Java project with that? I am on Mac, isn there any IDE for this quick and simple thing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't compile & run just one file in Eclipse without the file being in a java project.

It is a very quick and easy process to create a Java Project in eclipse.

```
File -> New -> Java Project
```

You can use the default package (though it is not recommended) and put your single file in it and run it.

Comment: I'd also stress that a "project" isn't doing anything complex behind the scenes, adding any code, etc. It isn't a framework. It's really just a folder to hold your work, with some settings files so that you can specify things like compilation options. I keep a project called "Scrap" that I use to test and play with snippets of code I'm working on, pasted code from SO questions, and the like.

Comment: Exactly! I do the same as you @maybeWeCouldStealAVan for running simple tests, etc. Thanks for highlighting this point.

Comment: Yes, that is there. I wish there was a way to open a file and run it without a project.

Comment: How exactly does this answer the question?

Comment: @AnubianNoob it doesn't, the OP updated their question with a solution that works for the OP. OP could have just made his own answer and accepted that

Answer (score 3):

Try [jGRASP](http://www.jgrasp.org/), it's a really simple editor and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in any Eclipse project with `org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature` (check/edit `.project` file).

So just open `.project` file and add

```
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
```

if it is not yet there.

Answer (score -2):

You can run the java file in the cmd command window.

make sure you have install the java environment.

```
java -version
```

output:
    java version "1.7.0_07"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_07-b11)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.3-b01, mixed mode)

```
cd javafilepath

java yourjavafilename.java
```

Comment: I'm not sure about other OS but on Unix you just put `java classname` without `.java`. After you compile it with `javac classname.java` Your answer doesn't answer the question btw.

Comment: The OP say: `The file is easily run via terminal using javac and then java, gives intended output`.

Comment: I can do that in cli. I wanted to do it right in IDE without going anywhere. Just quick and simple CMD+F11.

Comment: Yeah you do javac for Java Compile, then java to run.