# How to run a .java file in the eclipse after it was zipped?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to submit some project in my java course, so I created a zip file consisted of a .java file and other files.
Then to check that the .java runs correctly, I extracted it and got the file .java, double clicked on it and it was opened in the eclipse in a weird icon - a paper with the Letter J but it was in white, where usually it should be blue.
This program gets input in the run configuration, so I tried to give it the inputs and then run it, but it doesn't run, it pops a window:"select what to run" and the options are Ant Build

Comment: if you looking to create an executable jar file that runs without needing eclipse, here is a link on how to do that. http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37.htm

Answer (score 0):

The .java file is going to require a project in Eclipse to support it, or require you to compile the program through the console. You could replace your existing `.java` file with the zipped one (but they're identical).

Your instructor will likely know how to use the `.java` file. You'll need to use the files in the `dist` folder if you want to send a file/program that runs independent of the IDE.

The `.java` file is not an executable, and therefore double clicking it won't run the program, but merely opens the file in your IDE for further editing.

Comment: What should I do in order that my teacher will be able to run this program on his eclipse?

Comment: just send him the .java file. if you have used package-declarations, maybe its wise to remove them, to avoid compile-errors

Answer (score 0):

You have to compile your file first before running. try the following in command line:

```
cd path/to/javafile/folder
javac MyClass.java
java MyClass
```

Your Application should be execuded now.

Comment: @CnR This is what your professor will do. This is not going to change what you send to your professor for a grade.

Comment: yes, just enter it in the cmd-window. just replace the path and the classname by yours. if there are more .java files used in your program you have to compile them all with javac and run only the one, which contains the main()-method.

Comment: @leigero alright, so you're saying that I only need to send the .java file, and that's it, and if the other side want to run it in his eclipse he should type these commands?

Comment: @CnR Yes, that's pretty much it. they'll see the code you wrote. As I mentioned in my answer, the file isn't going to just run like an executable. They will know how to see your work. Just make sure you send all the .java files you made.

Comment: @CnR leigero is right, your professor might want to see, what you have written, because he maybe cant read bytecode like a book ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975422/how-do-i-run-a-single-java-file-having-main-in-eclipse-without-creating-an-en?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The default extension for Java source code is .java and .class is for compiled bytecode, which I believe is what you're trying to run/test.

Java programs are run by .class files.  If you want to be sure that your java code will run, you will first need to compile it with javac, or with eclipse (which runs javac for you with all the appropriate arguments).  Then you can run java from the command line (or via exclipse if you want) to make sure that your program behaves as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a New Java Project in Eclipse and then import your .java file in the src folder . It should run this way. You need of course a `public void main(String args[])` function in your .java file or in another .java file to test how the first works.